# Explanation of the 'scope' part of ordiR2step

Tags: r, vegan

I'm trying to use the ordiR2step function from the vegan package. I'm able to get the similar ordistep function working fine with:

```
mrday1<-rda(y1bio~y1local + y1region + y1comp + (y1local * y1region)....)
Aiy1<-ordistep(mrday1,perm.max=200)
Aiy1$anova
```

But I don't think I fully understand how the 'scope' piece works, so I neither trust that ordistep is giving me what I'm looking for nor can I get ordiR2step to work (it requires scope).

In the documentation it says that the scope:

> "Defines the range of models examined in the stepwise search. This
>   should be either a single formula, or a list containing components
>   upper and lower, both formulae."

with no example of it being used beyond

```
data(mite) 
data(mite.env) 
mite.hel = decostand(mite, "hel") 
mod0 <- rda(mite.hel ~ 1, mite.env)  # Model with intercept only mod1 <-
rda(mite.hel ~ ., mite.env)  # Model with all explanatory variables
step.res<-ordiR2step(mod0, mod1, perm.max = 200) 
step.res$anova  # Summary
#Note: this is a direct quote from the Vegan documentation
```

I'm confused on what the function of 'scope' is, and therefore how best to craft appropriate formulae for it.
I tried:

```
mrday0<-yda(y1bio~1,newAbioy1)
 mrday1<-rda(y1bio~y1local + y1region + y1comp + (y1local * y1region)....)
Aiy1<-ordiR2step(mrday1,scope=mrday0, perm.max=200)
Aiy1$anova
```

but without fully understanding what that scope bounding function did, I can't begin to evaluate the results. 
**Questions:**

**1) What does 'scope' actually do?**

**2) What kind of formula is it looking for?**

UPDATE

The complete and functional code I used is:

```
mrdayy02<-rda(y2bio ~ 1, datay2)
mrday2<-rda(y2bio~y2l + y2r 
         + y2c + y2lh + y2d
         + (y2l * y2r) + (y2l * y2c) + (y2l * y2lh) + (y2l * y2d)
         +               (y2r * y2c) + (y2r * y2lh) + (y2r * y2d)
         )
Aiy2<-ordiR2step(mrdayy02,scope=mrday2,direction="forward",R2scope= FALSE, perm.max=200)
Aiy2$anova

par(bg="transparent",new=FALSE)
plot(Aiy2,type="n",bty="n",main="RDAy2",
     xlab="RDA1",
     ylab="RDA2",
     col.main="black",col.lab="black", col.axis="white",
     xaxt="n",yaxt="n")
#abline(h=0,v=0,col="black",lwd=1)
points(Aiy2,display="species",col="gray",pch=20)
#text(rday2,display="species",col="gray")
points(Aiy2,display="cn",col="black",lwd=2)
text(Aiy2,display="cn",col="black",cex=0.5)
```

Comment: The vegan help example that you quoted would suggest usage `ordiR2step(mrday0, scope=mrday1)`. That is, you start from an empty model `mrday0` and work towards `mrday1` given as the `scope`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ordiR2step` works only with forward selection (this is documented). It starts with the model given as the first argument. The second argument `scope` gives the model to which tries to advance: `scope` must give the formula of the largest possible model (maximum model). I think this answers your first question.

The formula must be similar as the formula you use in your model. `ordiR2step` seems to be a kind function, and it will also extract the formula from the fitted ordination model.

Your example is unreproducible (and four dots in formula would give a syntax error). However, it seems to me that `myrday1` is your maximum model. So it should be used as the `scope`. Your `myrday0` contains only the constant (`~ 1`) and it can be used as the model to start with. It can be used as the first argument in your function. The following should work:

```
ordiR2step(myrday0, myrday1)
ordiR2step(myrday0, scope = formula(myrday1)) # same, but more explicit
```

In your own example you reversed the order of these models, and gave the maximum model as the first argument (= initial model). This will not work, because `ordiR2step` cannot go `backwards` (the another alternative `"both"` means that *after* a step forward, it will try to take one step back, but it cannot take the first step from the maximum model).

Comment: Fantastic explanation, thank you @Jari Oksanen ! I was totally misunderstanding the function all together, thinking it needed a lower and upper bound. Fixed my issue.

Comment: seeing as the author (@ Jari Oksanen)of the function is responding, I'd like to venture a follow up question: what is the maximum number of terms that can be fitted? Using your answer above the function is running fine with prelim code, but when I try to make my max model as big as I want it I get "the upper scope cannot be fitter (too many terms?)"

Comment: You can run out of degrees of freedom. Usually this manifests as a failure in getting the adjusted R-squared of the `scope` In most cases it helps to set argument `R2scope = FALSE`, and everything works (except that criterion on exceeding the adjusted R-squared of the `scope` will not be used).

Comment: absolutely perfect and thank you. I'm adding the complete updated code to the question. Thank you for your assistance.